# Detect Fn key with js

Tags: javascript, keypress

Hello I was wondering if it is possible to catch the fn key with js.
[image: fn key]

What i'm trying to achieve is detect the fn + f7 keypress.

Here is my code which is not triggered with the fn key :

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);

function onKeyDown(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Update : 
I found that detecting fn + f5 works on windows but not for my linux.
Is there a package to install to add media keys for firefox?

Comment: linked to this, the logical answer was to use keyup to detect the combination of keys...

Answer (score 8):

Most FN keys are implemented in firmware and won't be recognized by applications. You can use a website like this one to test out what javascript can handle:

http://keycode.info/

Comment: There's this other alternative https://keyjs.dev that has a bit more information about the different KeyboardEvents and their properties. 

Answer (score 6):

You can't catch when `fn` key was pressed.

However if you press `fn+F7` it would generate different `event` object than if you press solely `F7` - **considering that there is function bound to that key**. So in my case I do not have anything bound on F7, therefore there will be no event generated if I press `fn+F7` keys.

If I press `F3` and then `fn+F3`, following codes will be generated:

```
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "F3", code: "F3", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "AudioVolumeUp", code: "AudioVolumeUp", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
```

Hope this helps.

----More info below----

As I expected `fn` key does not really generate any keycode. Instead, on the hardware level, when pressed in combination with some other keys it is generating unique keycode.

Information based on answer from this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/827925/remapping-the-fn-key

And this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/270416/how-do-fn-keys-work

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);

function onKeyDown(e) {
 var x = e.keyCode;
 if(x==118){
  console.log('Your pressed Fn+F7');
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use keyUp instead of keyDown in your listener. Because you are doing a combination of keys.
And use the normal detection if (event.key === 'F2')...

Answer (score -1):

To find which key is pressed:

```
var intKey=self.setInterval(onkeydown="findKey(event);",5000);
function findKey(e)
{
  console.log("keyCode for the key pressed: " + e.keyCode + "\n");
}
```